# How to track if someone clicks a link to leave the page in mixpanel/GA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, mixpanel

I am trying to track an event when user tries to leave the website by clicking on a link.

```
<a ng-click="bookingOutside(trip,0)"  href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <button type="button" class="externalBooking">
            {{'BOOK'|translate}}
          </button>
        </a>
```

The bookingOutside event is never fired. Why is this? What can I do about it?

Comment: you should probably navigate to another window from bookingOutside function. remove the href from anchor tag and write window navigation code in bookingOutside function

Comment: It is illegal to put a button (or any other interactive content) inside an a element, so that may be affecting the bubble up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you set it up as the event just using this within the link should work, assuming you are using Universal Analytics. To my knowledge it should be in the  and not the button format.

ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons')

You can rename some of these to your liking as explained in the link below.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events